# How to avoid limits in Trigger's SOQL?

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, query, limits

I have a trigger. And if it's an import of many records I get an error becouse SOQL Limit is 101 records:

```
trigger GearCreationTrigger on Tool__c (after insert) { 
    List<Gear__c> toInsert = new List<Gear__c>();

    for(Tool__c tool : Trigger.new){
        List<Detail__c> details = [SELECT Info__c FROM Detail__c
                                    WHERE MoreInfo__c =: tool.MoreInfo__c LIMIT 1];

        Gear__c gear = new Gear__c(Tool__c = tool.Id);      
        if(details.size() > 0){
            gear.Info__c = details[0].Info__c;
        }
        toInsert.add(gear);
    }
    if(toInsert.size() > 0) insert toInsert;
}
```

How can I avoid limits in Trigger's SOQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<Detail__c> details = [SELECT Info__c FROM Detail__c
                                    WHERE MoreInfo__c =: tool.MoreInfo__c LIMIT 1];
```

this should be outside loop. First create a `List<String>` to hold MoreInfo__c of all tools the use it in SOQL with `IN` operator